# custom properties or special attribute or is this a pattern?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, encapsulation

I'am trying to figure out what programming technique they are using here. As you may see "Class AAA" has a type-class property called "MessageInfo". I need to know if this is a "custom property" or a kind of special attribute.

I tried by doing research and reading different books, and I'm still very confused.

```
public class AAA
{
    public BBB MessageInfo { get; set; }

    object.MessageInfo.text = "xxxxx";
}

public class BBB
{
    // text here... 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking. The code you show doesn't compile so, so I don't understand what the confusing part is. The property itself looks perfectly ordinary.

Comment: what is confusing you?

Comment: The line `object.MessageInfo.text = "xxxxx";` is not valid, as `object` does not contain a member called `MessageInfo`, nor can it ever do as `object` is built into .NET and cannot be changed. I suspect that line should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx), section 10.7:

A property is a member that provides access to a characteristic of an object or a class. Examples of properties include the length of a string, the size of a font, the caption of a window, the name of a customer, and so on. Properties are a natural extension of fields—both are named members with associated types, and the syntax for accessing fields and properties is the same. However, unlike fields, properties do not denote storage locations. Instead, properties have accessors that specify the statements to be executed when their values are read or written. Properties thus provide a mechanism for associating actions with the reading and writing of an object’s attributes; furthermore, they permit such attributes to be computed.

Click the link, download the specification, navigate to section 10.7, and add it to your reading list.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if this is a "custom property" or a kind of special attribute.

This is a property.

`In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property as you have in your example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.`.

Something like this

```
private BBB _bbb;
public BBB MessageInfo 
{ 
get{ return _bbb;}
set{_bbb= value;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a **Property** of type class BBB. And the .text in `object.MessageInfo.text` actually denotes another Public property inside class BBB.

You can have a look of this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) article about C# properties or this [ONE](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property).